# What does it mean that Instant.readObject method "Defend[s] against malicious streams"?

Tags: java, stream, java-8, java-time

Reading the source code for `Instant` class, I bumped into this method

```
/**
 * Defend against malicious streams.
 *
 * @param s the stream to read
 * @throws InvalidObjectException always
 */
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws InvalidObjectException {
    throw new InvalidObjectException("Deserialization via serialization delegate");
}
```

The description got me curious. What is a "malicious stream"? And how is this method defending against it?

Comment: A "malicious stream" is one that would make a naive decoder do something bad like allocate an enormous amount of memory or crash.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer? Seems an interesting topic

Comment: Note that it isn't specific to `Instant`. `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate` and others have this also.

Comment: Furthermore, it's private and never invoked... am I wrong?

Comment: It is called by the JVM. [Look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html) for more info.

Comment: I was thinking about that right now

Comment: TIL what a serialization delegate is, this must have something to do with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Instant`, and other `java.time` classes, are serialized using a package scoped delegate - `java.time.Ser`. See the `writeReplace` method to see how the delegate is created.

As such, the only way that the `readObject` method could be called is if someone was passing in a malicious stream (one created for the sole purpose of trying to create an invalid object). The exception ensures such malicious streams are blocked.

In general, any time that a serialization delegate is used, you should consider blocking `readObject` like this.

Answer (score 4):

Joshua Bloch the author of "Effective Java" has introduced [his idea](https://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=joshua%20bloch%20serialization%20proxy&source=bl&ots=yZGoQip2V_&sig=BR4cskP8LDqxl2H3RSamz0bWr08&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRl9vF_NPJAhWGlA8KHWYsAlYQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=joshua%20bloch%20serialization%20proxy&f=false) about the serialization proxy pattern. Very enlightening background to your question.

> With this writeReplace method in place, the serialization system will
>   never generate a serialized instance of the enclosing class, but an
>   attacker might fabricate one in an attempt to violate the class'
>   invariants. To guarantee that such an attack would fail, merely add this 
>   readObject method to the enclosing class...

```
// readObject method for the serialization proxy pattern
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidObjectException {
    throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy required");
}
```